# Dynamically allocating array of strings

Tags: c, arrays, string, malloc

I want to dynamically allocate array of strings, but I'm not sure how I can do this. So I thought of making a struct and dynamically allocate that struct. So I made the code below, but this code creates assertion failure.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    char str1[20];
    char str2[20];
} String;

int main(void)
{
    String * list;
    list = (String *)malloc(sizeof(String));
    int i = 1;

    for (; i < 6; i++) {
        realloc(list, i * sizeof(String));
        printf("Input String 1: ");
        scanf("%s", list[i - 1].str1);
        printf("Input String 2: ");
        scanf("%s", list[i - 1].str2);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        printf("%s\t%s\n", list[i].str1, list[i].str2);
    free(list);
}
```

What have I done wrong and how can I fix this problem?

Thanks :)

Comment: You are throwing away the result of `realloc`.

Answer (score 2):

The man page for `realloc` says:

> The realloc() function returns a pointer to the newly allocated
>   memory, which is suitably aligned for any kind of variable and may be
>   different from ptr, or NULL if the request fails.

The new pointer can be different from the one you passed to `realloc`, so you need to collect and use the pointer returned by `realloc`.

Answer (score 1):

A structure always has the same size so with this implementation you'd be stuck with always having an array of size 2.

A way to declare an array of strings (which are themselves arrays of characters) s doing

```
char **string;
```

If you want an array of 20 strings then that'd be:

```
string = malloc(sizeof(char*)*20);
```

Structs must have constant size, so i don't think the compiler will like you trying to allocate more memory for a structure than what it was defined with.